# Put the output of the model into an xlsx file into one column

Tags: python

I am running a model named Aspect-Based-Sentiment-Analysis.
The output of the model looks like this:

```
Sentiment.positive for "money"
Scores (neutral/negative/positive): [0.001 0.006 0.993]
None
```

I would like to put this output as a string into an xlsx file into one column (or that would be even more convenient separately into two columns: (1) a column 'sentiment' and (2) a column 'scores').
How can I make this?

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-create-and-write-on-excel-file-using-xlsxwriter-module/

Comment: somebody downvoted because of the format of the question.  usually it should be replicatable so that others can provide a complete solution.  Nevertheless, a solution (with an alternative) is provided.  `pandas` or `xlsxwriter` modules.

Answer (score 0):

I use Pandas a lot as it has the tools for this.

You can import `pandas` module at the top of your code:

```
import pandas as pd
```

The `pandas.DataFrame.to_excel` instructions can be found here:  https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html

firstly push the string to a Pandas DataFrame (however you like):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']],
                   index=['row 1', 'row 2'],
                   columns=['col 1', 'col 2'])
```

Then write to excel:

```
df1.to_excel("output.xlsx")
```

or

```
df1.to_excel("output.xlsx",
             sheet_name='Sheet_name_1')
```

It is quite straight forward.

One could also use the `xlsxwriter module` option which is given in the comments. You would use `import xlsxwriter`, but pandas is a more common package for datascience (and Python) and contains the same.

Comment: Thank you, D.L. Can you please say, how can I actually refer to the output that I extracted? How can I link it to your code? To be more precise: the output `Sentiment.positive for "money"
Scores (neutral/negative/positive): [0.001 0.006 0.993]
None` gives the following code: `absa.summary(money)`. Please, tell me if you need more details.

Comment: Yes,   you would need to push the strings into the dataframe.   Here is a link:  https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/text.html   .`pd.Series(["a", "b", "c"])`.  In the case of the question `a`, `b`, `c` would the the strings you required.

Comment: I am very sorry but I still do not comprehend. My output is just `Sentiment.positive for "money" Scores (neutral/negative/positive): [0.001 0.006 0.993] None`and it is not a string or whatever, it is a Nonetype object when I call `type(absa.summary(money))`. So I am not able to refer to it as you are describing. Maybe I really do not comprehend Python basics, but this is where I am stuck on.

Comment: There are only a few basic types in Python (as all languages). It must be of a type and you could cast that to a string. It is certainly not `None` as that represents an empty item and we see that it is not empty. You need to ammend the question to describe what you have tried, where it failed, and the exact outputs expected otherwise others may downvote your question.